# mandrill alternative for laravel (easy to setup)

Tags: php, laravel, email

I am a newbie to Laravel and have many problems in configuring the mail server. 
Is there any free and easy to set up mail service for Laravel?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure there are,

1. Sparkpost - https://www.sparkpost.com
   1.2 https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost
2. MailGun - https://www.mailgun.com
   2.2 https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php
3. Amazon SES (needs extra time amd configuration but is one of the best)
   3.2 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-u

And the list can go on:

4. Aritic Mail
5. ElasticEmail
6. SendGrid